# Move the new record entry row in Access table to the beginning row

Tags: ms-access-2010, record

Is it possible to move the "New Record Row" in an Access table to the beginning of the table?

For example, say you have 200 items entered into your table, you would have to scroll the whole way down to the bottom of the table to enter a new record.

Instead, your entry row would be in the first row of your table.

Can this be done?

Comment: Would this be more appropriate for the Super User site? It appears this may relate more to features of the application (tables, forms, etc.) rather than programming.

Comment: @JAGAnalyst No, it would not, the best way to do this is with a line of VBA, there are other ways, but VBA is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a form or datasheet and open it in add mode, rather than edit mode.

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", , , , acFormAdd
```

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx

Comment: Should this be added to one of the items under the `Event` tab of the form?

Comment: No, you can set up a form in Add Mode, but I see no reason why you should limit a form in that way, a few buttons or menu items will allow you to open the same form in a number of ways.